# ImportError for every third party library

Tags: python, pygame, python-import, importerror

I know there are similar questions, but I've looked at them and none of them are what I'm looking for

I'm running Python 3.7.0 on Windows 10, and I installed pygame-1.9.4 a few weeks ago, and it's been working fine until yesterday.

I have a file called testing.py that just contains:

`import pygame`

when I run it via

`C:\Users\Me>testing.py`, it returns the following error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame`

But when I'm in the Python shell, I can import it just fine

This is the case for every third party library. I have tested Pillow, flask, and others. Importing from the standard library works fine
I have uninstalled and reinstalled python and pygame, I've updated pip, I've updated setuptools as one person suggested, but none of it works

I had been using Wing IDE personal 6, and I could also run it fine from there, but I didn't care for it. Please help!

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: I am guessing that there are multiple python versions on your system and the one associated with `.py` files is not the one that you are using in the other cases. One hint could be to do `print(sys.executable)`, once inside a python file that you execute from the `cmd` and once written in your python shell. Then check for differences. Also check that `sys.path` is the same in each case

Comment: Thanks @FlyingTeller, when I ran it from the file it was using my GIMP python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that there are multiple python versions on your system and the one associated with `.py` files is not the one that you are using in the other cases.

To debug, what you can do is:
Write in a `.py` file

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

and also execute those lines from your python shell. That will print the path to the python interpreter that is executing said commands. The result will probably be different in your case.

What you can also do is check if

```
print(sys.path)
```

results in the same list using both methods, as it contains the folders being searched when importing